# On the day when ~ / When ~ - Is there a difference in nuance?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. I don't remember what I did on the day when I moved to my current house.
> 2. I don't remember what I did when I moved to my current house.

Is there any difference in meaning between the two sentences?  I feel they mean the same, but I'm not sure. Do you think they are the same meaning?

Comment: We'd normally say "on the day I moved to my current house" (without "when").   There is a difference between the two sentences:  "when" is more general than "on the day".  With "when", you could be referring to all of the preparations that led up to the move, not just to the actual day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context!

While '...when I moved..' is a broad sentence, '...on the day' is emphasizes the activities you did on **that day.**

---

In this context, you are defining the thing that is already defined. What all activities we do, we do it on *some or the other day*, don't we? So, here, you moved to your house, and further, you are defining 'that day' of moving!